# Is it safe to cast a lambda function to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

I have this code:

```
void foo(void (*bar)()) {
    bar();
}

int main() {
    foo([] {
        int x = 2;
    });
}
```

However, I'm worried that this will suffer the same fate as:

```
struct X { int i; };

void foo(X* x) {
    x->i = 2;
}

int main() {
    foo(&X());
}
```

Which takes the address of a local variable.

Is the first example completely safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I believe the first example is safe, regardless of the life-time of all the temporaries created during the evaluation of the full-expression that involves the capture-less lambda-expression.

Per the working draft (n3485) 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p6

> The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a
>   public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer
>   to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure
>   type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion
>   function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has
>   the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

The above paragraph says nothing about the pointer-to-function's validity expiring after evaluation of the lambda-expression.

For e.g., I would expect the following to work:

```
auto L = []() {
   return [](int x, int y) { return x + y; };
};

int foo( int (*sum)(int, int) ) { return sum(3, 4); }


int main() {
  foo( L() );
}
```

While implementation details of clang are certainly not the final word on C++ (the standard is), if it makes you feel any better, the way this is implemented in clang is that when the lambda expression is parsed and semantically analyzed a closure-type for the lambda expression is invented, and a static function is added to the class with semantics similar to the function call operator of the lambda. So even though the life-time of the lambda object returned by 'L()' is over within the body of 'foo', the conversion to pointer-to-function returns the address of a static function that is still valid.

Consider the somewhat analagous case:

```
struct B {
   static int f(int, int) { return 0; }
   typedef int (*fp_t)(int, int);
   operator fp_t() const { return &f; }
};
int main() {
  int (*fp)(int, int) = B{};
  fp(3, 4); // You would expect this to be ok.
}
```

I am certainly not a core-c++ expert, but FWIW, this is my interpretation of the letter of the standard, and I feel it is defendable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for "regardless of the life-time". After all, the created temporary lambda object is converted to a function pointer, its address is not used.

Comment: Would it still work correctly if `B::operator fp_t()` was returning a closure? Like `operator fp_t() const { return [](int x, int y) { return x + y; }; };`.

Comment: there is a typo but correct me if my wrong: ```foo( L )``` works, ```foo( L() )``` doesn't

Answer (score 21):

A lambda that captures *nothing* is implicitly convertible to a function pointer with its same argument list and return type. Only capture-less lambdas can do this; if it captures anything, then they can't.

Unless you're using VS2010, which didn't implement that part of the standard, since it didn't exist yet when they were writing their compiler.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to *Nicol*'s perfectly correct general answer, I would add some views on your particular fears:

> However, I'm worried that this will suffer the same fate as ..., which
>   takes the address of a local variable.

Of course it does, but this is absolutely no problem when you just call it inside `foo` (in the same way your struct example is perfectly working), since the surrounding function (`main` in this case) that defined the local variable/lambda will outlive the called function (`foo`) anyway. It could only ever be a problem if you would safe that local variable or lambda pointer for later use. So

> Is the first example completely safe?

Yes, it is, as is the second example, too.

Comment: "*Yes, it is, as is the second example, too.*" Pedantically speaking, the second example is illegal since it takes the address of a temporary, so it is neither safe nor unsafe. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Hah, didn't even realize this, me idiot. So what to do now, technically the whole answer might be rubbish, since the lambda example takes the address of a temporary, too. But then again it's a lambda and the function itself should practically *"be there"* all the time. Maybe it's time to comsult the standard for what seemed to be a pretty easy question.

Comment: The lambda example doesn't take the address of a temporary, it simply converts a lambda object to a function pointer. Anyway, IMHO your sarcasm is misplaced.

Comment: @enobayram *"Anyway, IMHO your sarcasm is misplaced"* - Could you please elaborate, what parts of my answer or comment you regarded as *"sarcasm"* (and no, this comment is not meant sarcastically, since I didn't intend anything to be sarcastic and would like to know which part seems to be).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was reading your comment with the wrong intonation :), I thought you found ildjarn's comment to be tangential to the subject and were being sarcastic in saying "technically the whole answer might be rubbish".