# Designing a better API for a variadic function

Tags: c++, api, c++11, variadic-functions

I'd like to wrap a variadic C++ function with a more modern C++11 style API.
The function is [this one](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/group__INS__INST__API.html#g82d2ecc73dcd5e2af26fef5bd6ff7190) from the [Pin instrumentation tramework](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool):

```
VOID LEVEL_PINCLIENT::INS_InsertCall(INS ins,
                                     IPOINT action,
                                     AFUNPTR funptr,
                                     ...)
```

Where `AFUNPTR` is declared as:

```
typedef VOID (*AFUNPTR)();
```

and the `...` is a list of arguments to pass funptr. The list is constructed of argument descriptors (`IARG_TYPE` enum), optional argument values, and a terminator `IARG_END` to denote the end of the list.

Here's a usage example for instrumenting a function before a given instructions (`ins`) that will print the contents of the rAX register:

```
void print_rax_and_tid(long rax, THREADID tid) {
    cout << rax << endl << tid << endl;
}

...

INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)print_rax_and_tid,
               IARG_REG_VALUE, REG_RAX, // the value of rAX register
               IARG_THREAD_ID,          // the thread id
               IARG_END)
```

Here we declare that our function will accept one argument that will hold a register value. We also request the tool to pass the value of the rAX register to the function.

Note that each function argument is described by one or two descriptors arguments:

- (`IARG_REG_VALUE`, `REG_RAX`) describes (`long rax`)
- (`IARG_THREAD_ID`) describes (`THREADID tid`)

The Pin framework sets the descriptors to know what to pass to the user function at runtime.

Also note that the type of the function arguments cannot be automatically deduced from the argument descriptors. In my example all the descriptors are enums, but they describe a long and THREADID argument.

I'd like to design this wrapper API with everything C++11 has to offer, possibly being able to pass a lambda instead of a function pointer, adding some type safety to the argument list, using variadic templates, etc.

Possibly the usage could look like this (but I'm open to suggestions):

```
INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, 
               [](long rax, THREADID tid) { cout << rax << endl << tid << endl; },
               IARG_REG_VALUE, REG_RAX,
               IARG_THREAD_ID)
```

Comment: "Inserting" a functionoid like a lambda would require the state to be stored somewhere.  If `INS_InsertCall` won't store the state, the API will have to require the caller to store the state.

Comment: This looks like a fascinatingly fun question, I'll have to come back and answer it when I get back to my computer in a few hours

Comment: If your talk about captured state, I'm fine with the lambda being stateless. The state can be handled as parameters to the lambda instead. Today it is also the case as the AFUNPTR is a static function pointer.

Comment: I don't know a way to tell stateless lambdas from stateful, and there isn't really a way to "store" the state elsewhere.  The callee would have to store the lambda itself between the `INS_InsertCall` and the actual invokation (whenever that may be).  Not a major problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a whole lot I could think to do with that API: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=045edb71ffca8062a9e016506e4b51f7-4f34a5fd633ef9f45cb08f8e23efae0a

```
struct REG_VALUE {
    IARG_TYPE arg = IARG_REG_VALUE;
    REG_TYPE reg;
    REG_VALUE(REG_TYPE r) :reg(r) {}
};
template<REG_TYPE reg_v>
struct REGISTER : REG_VALUE {
    REGISTER() : REG_VALUE(reg_v) {}
};

template<class func_type, class ...param_types>
VOID InsertCall(INS ins, IPOINT action, func_type funptr, 
    param_types... param_values) 
{ INS_InsertCall(ins, action, (AFUNPTR)funptr, param_values..., IARG_END); }
```

and then

```
InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, print_rax_and_tid, 
    REGISTER<REG_RAX>(), IARG_THREAD_ID);
```

I made the register a template type so you don't have to have the type/value pair, and then also made teh `IARG_END` automatic, but other than that, I don't understand enough of the API to understand what else could be automated.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Mooing Duck. I was hoping for being able to leverage lambdas but so far it doesn't appear to be feasible.

Comment: @OmerMor: Acording to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15657297/845092) only stateless lambdas are convertible to function pointers at all, so the ways to make stateless lambdas work would be quite tricky indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a template approach

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Runnable, typename... Types>
auto execute(Runnable f, Types... ts) -> decltype(f(ts...))
{
   return f(ts...);
}

// Some methods to test with:
void a() { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; }
void b(int) { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; }
void c(int, char) { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; }
int d() { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; return 0; }
int e(int) { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; return 0; }
int f(int, char) { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; return 0; }
int g() { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; return 0; }
void g(int) { std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; }

int main()
{
   int tmp = 1;
   char tmp_2 = '0';
   execute(a);
   execute(b, tmp);
   execute(c, tmp, tmp_2);
   execute(d);
   execute(e, tmp);
   execute(f, tmp, tmp_2);
   execute([](int){ std::cerr << __func__ << __LINE__ << "\n"; }, 0);
   execute(b); // This won't compile, as too few arguments provided.
   execute<int()>(g); // Explicit template instantiation needed (typename Runnable only)
   execute<void(int)>(g, 0); // Explicit template instantiation needed (typename Runnable only)
}
```

If you want to discard the return value of your function, the template becomes even simpler

```
template <typename Runnable, typename... Types>
void execute(Runnable f, Types... ts)
{
   f(ts...);
}
```

As you see, this works with lambdas too. If the function name is ambiguous, there is no way to avoid the explicit template instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, however I was probably not very clear about the requirements. The API should not just accept a function and its matching arguments. It accepts a function, and metadata that describes what we should pass to the functions. Sometimes a single value will describe an argument, and sometimes 2 descriptors will do the job for a single argument, as is the case in my example. Here IARG_REG_VALUE and REG_RAX are 2 enums that describe a single argument. The first tells that we accept a register value, and the second tells which register it is. I'll improve my question.

Comment: @OmerMor Why do you want to values describing one? Why wouldn't `REG_RAX` be enough?

Comment: I just described the existing API. I wouldn't mind having one descriptor in the final API. Take a look in the `IARG_TYPE` enum documentation for explanation on each descriptor and it's optional additional argument: http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#g7e2c955c99fa84246bb2bce1525b5681 . Remember that the descriptor type != argument type. The type that is mapped by the descriptor is documented in the same link.

Comment: @OmerMor Sorry, I don't get what you want to achieve. There is no way to have compile time checks that the combination of two enums has to result in a certain type, if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not totally clear. You should probably know a little about how the instrumentation tool works. It allows you to add enrich existing pre-compiled application binaries during runtime with your own instrumentation code. That can use it to measure, manipulate and do a lot of fun stuff. For example - Intel's vTune application is using it to do performance profiling.  The instrumentation API is the one I'd like to improve by wrapping. More information is in the links I provided.