# How to avoid non-standard behavior in taking the address of a standard library function

Tags: c++

Reading about [Designated addressable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Designated_addressable_functions), I realized that taking the address of a standard library function is undefined behavior.

Now, I do not know how to rewrite my code that always take the address of standard functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>

bool divisible_3(double n){
    return int(n)%3==0;
}

void applyFunction(std::vector<double>& vector, bool(* filterf)(double), double(*calc)(double)){
    for(int index=0;index<int(vector.size());index++){
        if(filterf(vector[index])){
            vector[index]=calc(vector[index]);
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    
    std::vector<double> vect = {1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 16, 21, 24};
    
    applyFunction(vect,divisible_3,std::sqrt);
    
    for(auto&& i: vect){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: According to the link you posted it is unspecified (not undefined) to use the address of a standard library function

Comment: you could always make your own function that just calls `sqrt`

Comment: The simplest way would be to write a function, which you can call, that calls `sqrt()`.       Incidentally, the terminology is taking "the address" not "the direction".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few choices. The first is the most obvious: write your own delegator function. `std::sqrt` might be a non-addressable function, but you know what is addressable?

```
double totally_not_std_sqrt(double input) {
  return std::sqrt(input);
}
```

This function is entirely addressable, so it can be passed in as an argument in completely standard C++.

The other, more compact option is to use a lambda.

```
applyFunction(vect, divisible_3, [](double x) { return std::sqrt(x); });
```

Now you might be thinking "lambdas are convertible to `std::function`, but I take a function pointer". That's true. But [lambdas that don't capture are convertible to function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657011/is-it-safe-to-cast-a-lambda-function-to-a-function-pointer), so even though your function takes a function pointer, it can still take non-capturing lambdas. (You might consider having your function take `std::function` though, unless you're planning on interfacing with C, but that's another issue)

Comment: Or unless you care about performance and inlining, which seem like more important in the majority of code bases